# before_update syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, rails-activerecord

post.rb Model

```
   after_update :assign_owner

   def assign_owner
      self.owner = "test"
   end
```

The above method works in terminal but does not change the value of Post.new.owner in Rails. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an after update (object needs to be saved) so

```
post = Post.new.save
```

Then

```
post.owner  # will be test
```

If you wanna do this you may want to use `after_initialize`

for e.g in post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  protected
    def after_initialize
      self.owner = "test
    end
end
```

Comment: A note of warning: since `after_initialize` is called for each object that is created, so also when finding them, i would add an extra test: `self.owner = "test" if self.owner.nil?` or `if self.new_record?` otherwise you will be changing the owner the whole time (to the current user for instance). Also note that this could be a serious performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

after_update only fires when you update your object. after_update will not call when you create.

You can use after_create callback when you want to call method on creating new object.

```
  after_create :assign_owner
   after_update :assign_owner

   def assign_owner
      self.owner = "test"
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

`after_update` and `after_create` are called after the object is saved. You do set the value of the `owner` but you don't save it.

Two possible options: use `before_update` instead --> your object is not yet saved and your change will be saved correctly.

Or use `after_update` and write it as follows:

```
def assign_owner
  self.update_attribute :owner, "test"
end
```

Note: any callback will only be called right before or right after saving, so `Post.new.owner` will still be wrong. But `Post.create(:context => 'blabla')` should trigger it correctly (or `Post.new.save`).

Hope this helps.